# Spring and Redis queue listener with annotation

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-data-redis

There is a way in Spring to configure Redis queue listeners using annotations?

I would like something like **Annotation-based SQS Queue Listener** from Spring Cloud for AWS, but using Redis as a queue.

Looking the documentation I can't find anything that fits well for me.

This feature is already implemented in Spring or I need implement it by my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Cloud Stream has support for redis